# It is possible to compress LESS files without removing comments using lessc?

Tags: less

I'm executing the following line to compress a less file:

```bash
lessc -x site.less site.css
```

And all my CSS blocks comment `/*foo */` are removed.

It is possible to *compress* my less files and *keep* the comments?

---

**Update**: Currently [SimpLESS](https://github.com/Paratron/SimpLESS) do it as of version 1.4, the change log said:

> if a LESS file starts with a CSS block comment, SimpLESS will *keep* that comment after minification (i.e. for Wordpress)

I would like to know if is it  possible to do it with `lessc` command.

Comment: Thanks @Stijn, it is not for debugging purposes but for WordPress that need a special comment at the beginning of the style.css file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to keep comments in compiled LESS files, you should be using block comments for non-minified code:

<sub>site.css</sub>

```
/* this is a keeper */
.foo {
    ...
}
```

And for minified code you should use `--yui-compress` with `/*!` to start your comments:

<sub>site.min.css</sub>

```
/*! this is a keeper */
.foo{...}
```

This is because the `lessc` command with the `--yui-compress` flag pipes the CSS through YUI Compressor, and [YUI Compressor allows comments when they begin with `/*!`](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/preserve-comments-yui-compressor/).

Comment: Thank! It worked when I use `lessc --yui-compress` but not with `lessc -x`. Can you clarify your answer to make clear that using `-x` will not work but that it will using `--yui-compressor`?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo, whoops, i misread the documentation (and didn't bother running an actual demo locally) I had assumed that `-x` was just a shorthand for `--yui-compress`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a relatively recent version of lessc then simply start the block comment with the `/*!` comment syntax.
eg

```
/*! This is preserved */
```

Previously you needed to use --yui-compress to get this to work, it now works by default.
The `yui-compress` option was removed a while ago (I haven't found the exact commit yet, but it was removed before November 2013).

This comment syntax also works with wordpress themes so you can preserve wordpress comment based meta data this way.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming to this now, since version 1.5 the less compiler uses clean-css instead of YUI. Use it like so:

```
lessc --clean-css [source-file] [destination-file]
```

Source: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/86